# How to overload non-const index operator for valarray class

Tags: c++, c++11

In the class below, when I try to return `std::valarray&` for `operator []`  it says: `invalid initialization of std::valarray& from R-Value reference std::valarray`.

I'm using it like so:

```
int main()
{
    Matrix<int> MM(4, 4);
    for (int I = 0, K = 0; I < 4; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < 4; ++J)
        {
            MM[I][J] = K++;  //Assigning to it does nothing atm :S
        }
    }

    for (int I = 0; I < 4; ++I)
    {
        for (int J = 0; J < 4; ++J)
        {
            std::cout<<MM[I][J]<<"  "; //Prints random values :l
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

and the class is as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
    private:
        int Width, Height;
        std::valarray<T> Elements;
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Argument T must be of arithmetic type.");

    public:
        Matrix(int Width, int Height);
        Matrix(T* Data, int Width, int Height);
        Matrix(T** Data, int Width, int Height);


        std::valarray<T>& operator [](int Index);
        const std::valarray<T>& operator [](int Index) const;
};

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Elements(Width * Height, 0) {}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(T* Data, int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Elements(Width * Height)
{
    std::copy(Data, Data + (Width * Height), &Elements[0]);
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(T** Data, int Width, int Height) : Width(Width), Height(Height), Elements(Width * Height)
{
    std::copy(Data[0], Data[0] + (Width * Height), &Elements[0]);
}


//ERROR below..
template<typename T>
std::valarray<T>& Matrix<T>::operator [](int Index)
{
    return Elements[std::slice(Index * Width, Width, 1)];
}

template<typename T>
const std::valarray<T>& Matrix<T>::operator [](int Index) const
{
    return Elements[std::slice(Index * Width, Width, 1)];
}
```

So my question is.. How can I overload the [] operator so I can get a single row or column so that I can index that and assign to it? I don't want to use the `() subscript operator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the non-`const` `operator[]` you have, this expression

```
return Elements[std::slice(Index * Width, Width, 1)];
```

This creates an `std::slice_array<T>` object, which is an rvalue. You cannot bind this to an `std::valarray<T>&`. The error can be fixed by changing the function to return a `valarray` by value instead of by reference.

```
template<typename T>
std::valarray<T> Matrix<T>::operator [](int Index) // <-- return by value
{
    return Elements[std::slice(Index * Width, Width, 1)];
}
```

Comment: Yeah but then I won't be able to change the value at that index inside the class using this operator.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Hmm, I don't see a way around that. `std::slice_array` doesn't define an `operator[]`, so the only way I see of applying the second `operator[]` is to create a `valarray` from it. But this, of course, means the operator needs to return the `valarray` by value. You may need to define an `operator()` after all.

Comment: Hmm I accepted your answer as I don't see any other way either. If I use a vector, is there a way to make it non-resizeable after construction?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Make the vector a private data member, and don't create any member functions that allow direct access to the vector. Then a user of your class will not be able to resize it. You may also want to take a look at [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) for ideas on how to implement your matrix class.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Another option is to make the vector member `const`. You can set the initial size in the constructor's initializer list, but the `const` will prevent you from resizing it later. You could also use a `unique_ptr<T[]>`.